# Nodejs fs.FSWatcher

Tags: node.js

I am using fs.watch() to watch changes in a directory. My code looks like this:

```
watchDirectory(){

        var watcher = fs.watch(this.directory, (event, filename) => {});

        return watcher;

    }
```

From Nodejs documentation:  `fs.FSWatcher` Objects returned from `fs.watch()` are of this type. However when I try to do something like this:

```
console.log(watcher instanceof fs.FSWatcher) //output fs.FSWatcher - undefined
```

Then I tried this:

```
console.log(watcher.constructor.name); //output FSWatcher
```

The question is **where I can find  the class of FSWatcher** if it does not exist in `fs.FSWatcher`?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FSWatcher` is a simple event emitter with convenient `start()/close()` methods. You can read [the code here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1300). As you can see, it's not exposed via `fs`. Are you trying to do something like this?

```
var fs = require('fs');

// instantiate the watcher
var watcher = fs.watch(__dirname);

// track changes later
watcher.on('change', function name(event, filename) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(filename);
});
```

Comment: Not really, I am writing a unit test where I want to test if watcher is an instance of FSWatcher.

Comment: @andrey That's why providing context is important. For your test, you can do a `watcher instanceof EventEmitter` (with `const EventEmitter = require('events');`), it should return true :) You can also check the existence of `watcher.start` and `watcher.close` if you want to be very thorough.